# Novel about a digital consciousness overtaking a person slowly

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel where a digital consciousness overtaking a person slowly, with both consciousnesses keenly aware of the process. A story similar to the primary storyline in Cyberpunk 2077.

I also vaguely remember the new consciousness being a better, smarter, and more likable person. Both consciousnesses also talk a lot about their thoughts on the process.

I wish I could provide more information, but this is all I have so far.

Comment: Do you recall when you would have read this?  Any idea about the cover art?  You're certain that even the consciousness being overwritten is aware of the situation?

Comment: I do not remember the cover art and I would have likely have read this in the early 2010s. As for the consciousness's awareness, is there a novel where the consciousness being overwritten is unaware of the situation?

Comment: High school? If so, there's one I'm trying to remember the name of might have originally been a play.

Comment: That is a strang euse of "overtaking".  As far as I know the meaning of the word "overtake" is for a being or vehicle travelling behind another one to travel faster and so  catch up with and pass the one which had been ahead.

Comment: @M.A.Golding (Oxford languages) 2a) (especially of misfortune) come suddenly or unexpectedly upon; 2b) (of a feeling) affect (someone) suddenly and powerfully.

Comment: The web comic "Schlock Mercenary" has DoytHaban (https://www.ovalkwiki.com/index.php?title=DoytHaban), who starts out as a human named Doyt Gyo with an combat suit controlled by the AI Haban 3122.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Heh, after my initial post, I wasn't so sure it was right anymore, since the book has less of a takeover happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Novel, or play, about a high school boy who gets a brain chip that gives him more personality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269313/novel-or-play-about-a-high-school-boy-who-gets-a-brain-chip-that-gives-him-mor/269314#269314), where I posted a question because I couldn't remember the name of the story I was looking for, and wasn't certain it was the same, could it be *[Be More Chill](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19476.Be_More_Chill)* by Ned Vizzini?

> Jeremy Heere is your average high school dork. Day after day, he stares at beautiful Christine, the girl he can never have, and dryly notes the small humiliations that come his way. Until the day he learns about the "squip." A pill-sized supercomputer that you swallow, the squip is guaranteed to bring you whatever you most desire in life. By instructing him on everything from what to wear, to how to talk and walk, the squip transforms Jeremy from Supergeek to superchic. Now an off-Broadway musical!

Found with a search for `site:goodreads.com "cool" brain chip`

After finding a summary that includes more of the later parts of the plot, it sounds like

> The book squip only influences Jeremy (although it's very convincing) while the ones in the play actually do make a takeover play (no pun intended) although in both cases, they eventually are disabled.